# Pass by reference, with a variable numbers of parameters in PHP?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

I have a function that takes a variable number of parameters, and I have to pass them *by reference* to another function.

Such as

```
function my_function($arg0, $arg1, $arg2, ...)
{
    my_other_function(&$arg0, &$arg1, &$arg2, ...); 
}
```

So that when I pass things by reference to `my_function`, `my_other_function` also gets them by reference.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: hmmm... func_get_args ? no, it didnot work

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that if I just use it as is, the passed-by-reference values will get passed by copy to the other function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder why you need this. In general [references are bad](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html) in PHP.

If you really want to do this the only proper way (ignoring call-time pass-by-ref hacks, which won't work with PHP 5.4 anymore anyways) is to use an array wrapping the parameters:

```
function myfunc(array $data) {
    $data[0] += 42;
    /* ... */
}

$var = 0;
myfunc(array(&$var /*, ... */));
echo $var; // prints 42
```

For passing to the other function you can then use [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/call_user_func_array)

Comment: Great, this worked for me. As for why I'm using it, this is for some meta-programming features in my framework.

Comment: Still references seem to e the wrong solution. Maybe wrap stuff that has to be changed in objects? (Remember objects are passed by handle - which mostly feels like passing them by ref)

Answer (score 1):

Technically you are not doing this:

```
function my_function($arg0, $arg1, $arg2, ...)
{
    my_other_function(&$arg0, &$arg1, &$arg2, ...); 
}
```

but this:

```
function my_function(&$arg0, &$arg1, &$arg2, ...)
{
    my_other_function($arg0, $arg1, $arg2, ...); 
}
```

However as @johannes [already wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11595899/367456), there is no good support for variable number of arguments that are references in PHP (and who could know better). [`func_get_args`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/func_get_args) for example does not work with references.

Instead make use of the suggestion to pass all references via an array parameter. That works.

```
function my_function(array $args)
{
    my_other_function($args); 
}
```